# Transforming Many E2ETraceEvent Via XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a 3rd party application that generates Microsoft `<E2ETraceEvent/>` nodes so there are basically many root nodes I cannot figure out if there is there a way to tell ignore the multiple root problem with XSLT without creating another process to wrap a root element around the entries?  If so how?

Basically the XML file contains many entries like the following

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <EventID>1</EventID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-10-21T16:38:10.0421996Z" />
        <Source Name="Framework" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessName="Framework" ProcessID="2448" ThreadID="15" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer>WIN</Computer>
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>
        <TraceData>
            <DataItem>
                <TraceRecord Severity="Error" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord">
                    <TraceIdentifier>Framework</TraceIdentifier>
                    <Description>Killing unresponsive jobs.</Description>
                    <AppDomain>JobHost</AppDomain>
                </TraceRecord>
            </DataItem>
        </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: What XSLT engine? Invoked from the command line or a program?  If from a program, you could filter the input and pass each element as a separate document.  Without more details on how you're expecting to invoke the transformation, it's hard to provide a solution.

Comment: The engine is .net but I have no programing control over it, I'm only able to select the XSLT and XML.

Comment: In that case I seriously doubt you can do this, unless the .net engine provides a non-standard option specifically for this.  There's nothing in the XML or XSLT specs that would allow this.  You should post this question on a .net XSLT support forum instead.

Comment: That's what I thought Jim. Thanks for taking time to respond. I posted the question here being I have no control of the .net code that is used for applying the XSLT to the XML so it would be a waste of their time responding. I was hoping I could do some sort of copy into a root node natively in XSLT.

Comment: How is this engine invoked? Do you specify the XML and XSLT files on the command line, and it outputs to a file? If so, then you could pre-process the multi-root XML to wrap it with a root node, then send the wrapped file to your XSLT tool.

Comment: It's web based so its basically select and execute.

Comment: The poors man "fix" to this is to put an artificial document element to group all the elements. Depending on how the transformation is invoked you could also create an XmlReader with ConformanceLevel set to "Fragment" then you could invoke transformation with a new reader with ReadSubtree until you read the whole file.

Comment: Select what? Execute what? Can you pre-process the XML file to be transformed?

Comment: Pawel - I don't have access to change the .net code so that isn't going to work.
Jim - The web interface has a browse option for the XML file and then a browse option for the XSLT.  Then the backend performs the transformation with codebehind.